# Displayed Rank of Count In a Power BI Table all showing as 1

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a query with the a Course Column. In a table, I'd like to view all the courses with a count of course instance and a rank of that count.
I've added a table to my report. I then created a TotalCourses measure :-

```
TotalCourses = CALCULATE(COUNT(QUERY1[Course:]))
```

I added this to the table, and the count is correct. I then created another measure for the ranking :-

```
CourseRanks = RANKX(ALL(Query1),[TotalCourses],,DESC)
```

I added this to the table, but all the ranks are showing as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below code-

```
Ranks = 
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( QUERY1[Course:] ),
    RANKX ( ALL ( QUERY1[Course:] ), [TotalCourses] )
)
```

**Or** only-

```
Ranks = RANKX(ALL(QUERY1[Course:]),[TotalCourses])
```

Answer (score 0):

RANKX (ALL(Query1),COUNTX(RELATEDTABLE(QUERY1),[Course]))
The above should calculate the ranking by count of course from query1 over query1